# How to match two dataframes, and add value from on dataframe to the other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a training dataset with 87k data points. Looks like this.

```
index street_name    street_name_categorical
0     Nyhavn           1
1     Nyhavn           1
2     Gotgade          2
3     Botgade          3
4     Marmorgade       4
...
```

87k rows in total.

This is a new dataset which I would like to test on, but add the categorical values from the training data to the new dataset.

New Dataset

```
index street_name
0     Nyhavn
1     Marmorgade
2     Gotgade
3     Totgade
4     Gotgade
...
```

1.4k rows in total.

Desired output would be in the new dataset:

```
index street_name    street_name_categorical
0     Nyhavn         1
1     Marmorgade     4
2     Gotgade        2
3     Totgade        NA
4     Gotgade        2
...
```

Should return 1.4k rows.

I tried the following lines of code, but it does not return the desired output.

```
street_name_cat_from_train = train[["street_name","street_name_cat"]]
merged_df = new_data.merge(street_name_cat_from_train, on = ['street_name'])
merged_df
```

Returns 197k rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since categories are unique, create a dictionary to map names to category values

```
dt = df.groupby('street_name').first()['street_name_categorical'].to_dict()
```

Map street names with the `dt`

```
df2['street_name_categorical'] = df2['street_name'].map(dt)
```

Comment: Gives me an error on the first line: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @doomdaam what's the stack trace? is it having trouble at the `groupby()`, `first()`, or `to_dict()`?

Comment: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'" it says at the groupby()

Comment: It figured it out. dt = train.groupby('street_name')['street_name_cat'].first().to_dict()
 is the correct way

Comment: Soz, had to get back to work so did it in a hurry and didn't tailor to your variable names

Comment: Np. It was the positioning of first(). It had to go after the street_name_cat variable